# Incompatible int to String (getLast() method)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a string array

```
 String[] names;
```

lets say there are a given number of elements in the array

I would like to make a getLast method which returns a string

```
  public String getLast() {

    return names.length - 1; 

}
```

This gives me an error that it's incompatible.

How could I do this to return a string?

Also the same with an add method

```
 public void add(int index, String element){
```

I'm curious how this would work without using Linkedlist or Arraylist, but rather an Array-based list.

Comment: Access the array with the index you've calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Get last element:*

```
   public String getLast() {
        return names[names.length - 1];
      }
```

*Add a String element to the array*

```
    public void add(int index, String element) {
    int len = names.length;
    if (index < len)
      names[index] = element;
    else {
      names = Arrays.copyOf(names, len + (index - len + 1));
      names[index] = element;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks! for making an addLast or addFirst, would I just make a slight variation of that add method?

Comment: Sure, Keep in mind to shift elements if required depending on how you define `add` methods!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
public String getLast(){
   return names[names.length-1];
}
```

`[]` is Array access by index.
If an array A has size 10, the last item is A[9].
That's because numbering always starts from 0.

For the *add* method, you need to access the array element by the given index and substitute it's value:

```
public void add(int index, String element){
   names[index] = element;
}
```

Comment: can you explain to the op why [] are needed?

Comment: @KickButtowski : read yourself http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: [] is Array access by index.

Comment: @g7k could you please add your comment to your post and explain so I can vote you up?

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
public String getLast() {
    return names[names.length - 1]; 
}
```

If it's not obvious to you, you should take a deeper look into [Java Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

> I'm curious how this would work without using Linkedlist or Arraylist,
>   but rather an Array-based list.

ArrayList **is** an array-based list.

Answer (score 1):

Your current getLast() is returning an int (`names.length - 1`) when it's expecting a string. You can correct this by accessing the last index of the array.

```
public String getLast(){
   return names[names.length-1];
}
```

What do you imagine `add(int index, String s)` to do? Say I'm adding at an index that is already populated by another string. Should it overwrite? Or shift all of the following elements down to make room?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getLast()
{
   return names[names.length -1];
}
```

You need to access the array at postion length - 1 which is the last position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String getLast() {
    return names[names.length - 1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method return an int where it should return a String :

```
public String getLast() {
   return names.length - 1; 
}
```

it should be

```
public String getLast() {
   return names[names.length - 1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

names.length - 1 is an integer, the index to the last String in the String array . You're looking for the last String, so you can use the index to access the last element.

```
public String getLast() {
    return names[names.length - 1];
}
```